# ArangoDB: Is it always necessery to have a document collection for use in edge collection?

Tags: arangodb

Assume I have three document collections: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and an edge collection `links` keeping relations between them.

Now I need a new concept of a `pin` which is a short string, label pinning together a triplet of one `foo`, one `bar`, and one `baz` logically.

Am I obligated to create and maintain a new collection for pins even though, there will be no data stored in such collection besides the keys (`pin` strings themselves?)

Is there some other approach or common practice for such cases or keeping an collection of empty documents is the only way?